# Data Type of Color.?? to create a model class in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Hi I've a question to create a json response to model class in flutter.

My response from API is like this :

```
{

    "status": 200,
    "message": "data fetch successfull",
    "data": [{
            "view_type": 1,
            "heading_title": "Trending Now",
            "trend_list": [{
                "title": "",
                "subtitle": "",
                "price": 1500,
                "display_image": "",
                "size": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                "rating": 4,
                "isFavourite": false,
                "container_color": ["0xFF559BE2", "0xFF2F53CB"],
                "image_shoe": [{
                    "shoe_image": "",
                    "color": "0xFF559BE2",
                    "container_color": ["0xFF559BE2", "0xFF559BE2"]
                }, {
                    "shoe_image": "",
                    "color": "0xFF559BE2",
                    "container_color": ["0xFF559BE2", "0xFF559BE2"]
                }, {
                    "shoe_image": "",
                    "color": "0xFF559BE2",
                    "container_color": ["0xFF559BE2", "0xFF559BE2"]
                }, {
                    "shoe_image": "",
                    "color": "0xFF559BE2",
                    "container_color": ["0xFF559BE2", "0xFF559BE2"]
                }, {
                    "shoe_image": "",
                    "color": "0xFF559BE2",
                    "container_color": ["0xFF559BE2", "0xFF559BE2"]
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

So My Problem is in Container Box Decoration  gradient Color accept Color not in String.

So what will be Data type should I add in Model class.?

Comment: I will suggest to  check [guides on JSON](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)

Comment: If possible ask your back end developer to send it as an int and You can directly pass it to the color, like this `Color(0xFF559BE2)`

Comment: You can add string as data type and you then convert it to int as Color accepts int convert string to int or as @ibhavikmakwana says you can do that also

Comment: Thank you @ibhavikmakwana for suggesting good idea, I've achieved by doing as you suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model class can have a color.

You can get a color from your string in JSON by first parsing it as an integer and then creating a color from that integer:

```
yourModelPropertyOfTypeColor = Color(int.parse("0xFF559BE2"))
```